# XML - Write a single node

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I got this function for simply get the inner text of my xml:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("game.xml");
string content = document.SelectSingleNode("Game/Client-Version").InnerText;
```

(this is the xml file (due to complications with stackoverflow posted on pastebin)): http://pastebin.com/EEeFAJpC

And now I am exactly looking for the function above, just to write. Like

```
document.WriteSingleNode("Game/Client-Version", "texttowrite");
```

I did not find anything helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
XmlElement x = document.SelectSingleNode("Game/Client-Version") as XmlElement;
x.InnerText = "texttowrite";
```

Comment: Thanks! I also found out another way - `xDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
            xDocument.Descendants("Language").First().Value = language;
            xDocument.Save(xmlPath);`

Answer (score 0):

Create your own extension method:

```
public void WriteSingleNode(this XmlDocument document, string NodeName, string InnerText)
        {

            // Create a new element node.
            XmlNode newElem = document.CreateNode("element", "pages", "");
            newElem.InnerText = InnerText;

            Console.WriteLine("Add the new element to the document...");
            document.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newElem);

            Console.WriteLine("Display the modified XML document...");
            Console.WriteLine(document.OuterXml);
        }
```